# Interpretation of CCF plot

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, lags

I am using ccf on two univariate time series to find out which variable is leading and which is lagging. My result is something like shown in the plot
[image]

Can I really tell anything from this plot? Does it mean that x is both leading and lagging y?

The ACF value drops when the lag reaches 0 but still exceeds the boundary.

**edit:**
Attached you find both timeseries plotted:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you prewhiten?

Comment: I suspect non-stationairy time series. Can you plot both time series?

Comment: I did not prewhiten the timeseries before. @Ruben I attached both timeseries. Both are the longterm trend components without seasonal changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a valid interpretation of the cross correlation function, time series need to be wide sense stationary. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Cross-correlation_function) Looking at the graphs, both of your time series are not stationary. So it is not ok to interpret this ccf graph.

You can still examine the correlation between these two time series, by checking if the differenced time series are stationary and computing the correlation of the differenced time series in case of stationarity.